# Create a new column by aggregating multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

**Background**

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to aggregate multiple columns and create a new column. I need to multiply Type, Span and Population columns and create a new Output column

```
ID       Status      Type     Span   State   Population

A        Yes         2        70%    Ga      10000
```

**Desired output**

```
ID        Status     Type      Span   State   Population   Output

A         Yes        2         70%    Ga      10000        14000
```

**dput**

```
structure(list(ID = structure(1L, .Label = "A ", class = "factor"), 
Status = structure(1L, .Label = "Yes", class = "factor"), 
Type = 2L, Span = structure(1L, .Label = "70%", class = "factor"), 
State = structure(1L, .Label = "Ga", class = "factor"), Population = 10000L), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

**This is what I have tried**

```
 df %>% 
 mutate(Output = Type * Span * Population)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we are creating a new column based on the inputs from different column.  We can just use `mutate` to get the `Span` percent of `Population` and multiply by 'Type'.  Note that 'Span' is not numeric, as it is having `%`, so we extract the numeric part with `parse_number` divide by 100, then multiply with Population along with the 'Type'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Output = Type * Population * readr::parse_number(as.character(Span))/100)
#   ID Status Type Span State Population Output
#1 A     Yes    2  70%    Ga      10000  14000
```

---

If the columns 'Type', 'Population' are not numeric, it is better to convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric(as.character(df$Type))` and for 'Population' (assuming they are `factor` class).  Another option is `type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)` and then work on that modified class dataset

Comment: ok thank you I will try, I am sure it is my full dataset, but I keep getting this error: Error in "No. of Doses" * Population : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator   Does this mean one of my columns must be converted to numeric?

Comment: @Lynnette is the error based on the dput or a different dataset

Comment: @Lynnette with your `df`, I get Type and Population as integer and Span factor, which is converted to character while extracting the numbers

Comment: @Lynnette okay, can you please check `str(df)`  if Type or Population are factor, then convert to numeric i.e. `as.numeric(as.character(df$Type))`

Comment: Type and population are integers, should I still convert?

Comment: @Lynnette okay, then it is a problem with your 'Span' column.  I assume that you have only '%' at the end in your column.

Comment: @Lynnette what is `No. of Doses` Have you used backquotes on that column?

Comment: I do  total<- mergeUN %>%
    mutate(Demand = 'No. of Doses' * Population * readr::parse_number(as.character(Coverage))/100)

Comment: @Lynnett Can you do this without the `No. of Doses` or backquote that column name instead of single quote

Comment: ah ok, so it is the way the column is structured. Oh how did you know I have a 'No of Doses Column' ha! ok thank you!

Comment: @Lynnette Though my eye sight is weak, it picked up that from the Error comment :=)

Comment: oh yes it worked! thank you, there seems to not be as much aggregation documentation, as I have tried to research this myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can remove the `'%'` sign using `sub`, convert to numeric and multiply values.

This can be done in base R as :

```
df$output <- with(df, Type * as.numeric(sub('%', '', Span)) * Population/100)
df

#  ID Status Type Span State Population  output
#1 A     Yes    2  70%    Ga      10000   14000
```